# Vs 2017 rdlc: html in textbox is ignored

Tags: visual-studio-2017, rdlc

I'm trying to create a new report (rdlc) and I'd like to use html (b tag). Unfortunately, the tag is ignored and the  tag is rendered as is. According to my searches, there should be an option for setting the contents of a textbox as html, but i can't see that option in the designer.

Does anybody know if this feature is still supported. If so what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right click on «Expr» not at text box,
2. Choose Place Holder Properties
3. In Markup Type Section Select HTML - Interpreter HTML tags as style
4. OK.

If Place holder properties option not coming after Right Click then try to select «Expr» and Right click on «Expr».

if you send `<B>Imran Ali Khan</B>` then It will be **Imran Ali Khan**